# Running command from TeamCity fails, but running it in the terminal it succeeds

Tags: server, permissions, mono

I am attempting to build an ASP.NET MVC 4 project. From the terminal it succeeds. I am logged in as my admin account. Teamcity was installed with its' default settings.

From the command prompt:

```
xbuild /var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/8873763565ce1ac8/Source/Momntz.UI/Momntz.UI.csproj /t:Rebuild /p:config=Debug/var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/8873763565ce1ac8/Source/Momntz.UI/Momntz.UI.csproj /t:Rebuild /p:config=Debug
```

From Teamcity:

```
/opt/mono-2.11/bin/xbuild /var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/8873763565ce1ac8/Source/Momntz.UI/Momntz.UI.csproj /t:Rebuild /p:config=Debug
```

Error:

```
/opt/mono-2.11/bin/dmcs: 2: /opt/mono-2.11/bin/dmcs: mcs: not found
/opt/mono-2.11/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.CSharp.targets: error : Compiler crashed with code: 127.
Task "Csc" execution -- FAILED
```

It feels like a permissions issue, but I'm new to Ubuntu and I don't know how to go about tracking the issue down.

Answer (score 1):

Try to stop build agent, and start it via /bin/agent.sh start command in order to make agent run under your environment. This would let you know if the issue is in agent or environment.

You may call export command to compare user environment and agent environment. Probably you need to call /bin/bash --login before starting agent.sh as daemon

Comment: I tried running the agent.sh under sudo. Still encountered the same issue. I was hoping that was the issue. Bummer. The export command is a great idea.